# how to paginate a variable that return data laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My code is given below in laravel:

```
$events = $this->eventRepo->getEvent($lat,$lng,$radius);
```

Here `$event` gives me a list of data.
But i want to make convert paginate data from here. I can't use paginate function. I got many errors.

Answer (score 0):

In `getEvent()` function return paginated object.
Like:

```
function getEvent () {
     return YourModel::paginate(10);
}
```

`$events` will receive the paginated object then you can use it to list out your data. Cheers.